# Using Java's LocalDateTime for SAML 2.0 based time values

Tags: java, saml, opensaml

I am currently working on a SAML 2.0 based Web Browser SSO profile implementation for Apache Tomcat in the form of a valve.

I had been using org.joda.time.DateTime to set values for date-time related attributes such as, IssuerInstant.

The following has been specified in SAML 2.0 core spec in using time values for implementations:
"All SAML time values have the type xs:dateTime, which is built in to the W3C XML Schema Datatypes
specification [Schema2], and MUST be expressed in UTC form, with no time zone component.
SAML system entities SHOULD NOT rely on time resolution finer than milliseconds. Implementations
MUST NOT generate time instants that specify leap seconds."

Java's [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) does seem to satisfy majority of the conditions but is the final condition related to leap seconds satisfied? I have searched several resources for any idea about this but I have not been successful.

Can we use [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) for the above mentioned purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalDateTime does not take into account leap seconds. I believe you are safe to use it

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the answer but later I came across the restriction where we are to use org.joda.time.DateTime in OpenSAML library methods such as, setIssueInstant.

Comment: Well, that pretty much ties you to Joda library and gives you no lee way. Joda library is a good and popular one, but in my opinion java 8 new date and time package supersedes it. Best of luck anyway